# CallBack in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-callbacks

How we use CallBack in WCF fluently with events and delegates?

If Client give any request or any conditions matches of client then services automatically fire the event which condition or request given from client.

how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner model is an event driven one using a Publish/Subscribe Pattern. 
 Read this to get inside onto both methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You basically define a service method as one-way and also create a message callback. See more here: http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx